# Html agility cant get the results

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have this list of URLs on following webpage, I am wondering how do I grab the URLs and add them to a ArrayList?

http://www.manta.com/mb?search=U.S.+Cellular&refine_company_loctype=B

I tried doing it myself and for whatever reason i didnt get any results
here is the code

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    doc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString("http://www.manta.com/mb?search=U.S.+Cellular&refine_company_loctype=B"));

    var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='clear']")
        .Descendants("a")
        .Select(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value)
        .ToArray();

    foreach(var item in links)
    {
        Response.Write(item.ToString()+"---new line---<br/>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, web site, which you are trying to scrape has protection with captcha and/or timeout against to many requests to web site.

So you should take that into account. In this case you become different web page without your divs.

Second, you are selecting only one node from document by SelectSingleNode, so it returns only one node.

So try following code:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

    doc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString("http://www.manta.com/mb?search=U.S.+Cellular&refine_company_loctype=B"));                

    var divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='clear']");

    if (!divs.Any())
        Response.Write("Not found or timeout protection mechanism");

    foreach (var item in divs)
    {
        HtmlNode link = item.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
        Response.Write(link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));
    }
}
```

Comment: beat me to it, the only thing i'd change would be to check if `divs` is null since the Agility Pack doesn't return an empty collection but null.

Comment: no, not only. Instead of "doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode" you should use "doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes". Anyway, you could use code as a working sample, because I've tested it against your web site

Comment: oh, i was talking about your code, not the one in the question. also, i'm not the one asking in case you didn't notice :)

Comment: @shriek ааа, but truly speaking, it returned empty not-null collection in this case. It's not important and I can add this check, but I've checked it with debugger - not-null empty collection in cse, when no such divs on page

Comment: ah, seems i'll have to test this with the latest version, maybe they finally fixed this "flaw" for the better and return a empty collection now.

Comment: @Regfor thank for solution actually i am very new to this all data scrapping thing try to learn my self still dont know how to deal empty collection do you have any solution for this if you have please help me thank you

Comment: @JayZee For empty collection just check for null and/or for LINQ Any like on sample